# Error when converting byte array to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using C# 4.5 Framework and `MySql`

```
MySqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{

   byte[] ReturnImage = reader["Photo"] as byte[];

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ReturnImage);

   Image Photo = Image.FromStream(ms);  //Error is in this statement!! 
}
```

When this stmt is executed the following error displays "Parameter is not valid"

I couldn't find the answer from the web.. Somebody Pls help..

Comment: what is `reader` and are you sure it is a byte array?

Comment: @Sayse if it wasn't a `byte[]`, I would expect the first line to return a `null`, and therefore the second line to throw an `ArgumentNullException`

Comment: How did you **store** the data here? Meaning: what is the binary contents? are you sure it genuinely is a raw, but intact, image?

Comment: Either your your stream is null or it doesn't have a valid image format

Comment: MarcGravell - Very true..

Comment: @Sayse Yes, it is a byte array.

Comment: Marc Gravell Ya, it is a genuine image

Comment: @Rejith but again: are the contents a *valid and intact* image? It is entirely possible that it was corrupted during storage, or that the contents are actually in some kind of wrapper rather than being a raw image

Comment: @Rejith Here's the thing: you can say "it is a genuine image", but: `Image` disagrees with you. I'm inclined to believe `Image` more. So: ***how did you store it***?

Comment: the image was stored in a mysql table column type is LongBlob

Comment: @Rejith but again, *how* did you store it; what steps did you go through when you stored the data? Precisely what the blob contents are, and how you stored it is **very important** here... `LongBlob` is entirely appropriate and fine, but that is only half the story. A `LongBlob` that contains something that isn't quite the raw image *doesn't help*.

Comment: It is not __where__ but but __how__ did you store __what__?

Comment: using OpenFileDialog i have selected an image (.jpg) and put it in a picture box. then i set the picture box background image to a variable of type Image. By using a Stored Procedure i have passed the blob parameter and saved the image.

Comment: @Rejith please show the storing code in the question.

Comment: "By using a Stored Procedure i have passed the blob parameter and saved the image." - assuming that your stored procedure doesn't do anything crazy (but rather: just assigns the blob to the column) - the very important question here is: *what **exactly** was the value of the parameter*

Comment: MySqlCommand Command = HRMDBConfiguration.MySQLConnection.CreateCommand();
            Command.CommandText = "Person_Proc_Create_Photo";
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Command.Parameters.Clear();


            MySqlParameter p1 = new MySqlParameter("PhtoId", MySqlDbType.Int64);
            p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            Command.Parameters.Add(p1);

Comment: MySqlParameter p2 = new MySqlParameter("Phto", MySqlDbType.LongBlob);
            p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p2.Value = photoBO.Photo;
            Command.Parameters.Add(p2);

            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            photoBO.PhotoId = Convert.ToInt64(p1.Value);

Comment: We're going around in circles; now the immediate question is: "what is `photoBO.Photo`, and how did it get its value?". However, I am adding an answer that should hopefully help a bit...

Comment: @ Marc Gravell Raw Format: {b96b3cae-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e}

Comment: @Rejith that is a guid, not a jpg...

Comment: @Marc Gravell photoBO.Photo is a variable of type Image. It gets value from the picture box background image property. Anyways thank u very much Mr.  Marc Gravell.. I will try ur answer.. hope it works.. once again thank u very much...

Comment: @Rejith an `Image` instance is **not** the raw image; it is a complex object model *about* an image. To store the blob from file-contents, all you need is the file-contents; for most images (i.e. not huge), you can probably just use `File.ReadAllBytes`.

Comment: Yes, u r right.. it Reports Failure.. now i think the error is in the following code where i prepared the image to be stored

Comment: OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            dialog.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;";

            dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

            dialog.Title = "Select an Image";

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                picturebox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);

                Image Photo = picturebox.BackgroundImage;
            }

Comment: @Marc Gravell Can you please provide the code to prepare the image to be stored??

Comment: @Rejith `p2.Value = File.ReadAllBytes(path);` - done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause here is that the contents of the `longblob` are *not* the raw image bytes. Rather than go around in circles, the first thing to do is to: **compare them**. For example, you say (comments) that the data came from a jpg file, via `OpenFileDialog`. In that case, **compare them**. Check that you have successfully stored and retrieved the image.

Let's suppose that the file in question is `c:\Some\Photo.jpg` - stored etc per whatever process. In that case, you should be able to check the contents are the same. Until the following reports success, **all bets are off**:

```
byte[] original = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\Some\Photo.jpg");
byte[] ReturnImage = reader["Photo"] as byte[];

if(Convert.ToBase64String(original) == Convert.ToBase64String(ReturnImage)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Success; the contents match");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Failure; the contents are different");
}
```

If this reports "Failure; the contents are different", then the error is most likely in one of:

- the code where you prepare the image to be stored (populating parameters etc)
- the stored procedure that does the storage
- the code that fetches the image back from the database

If this reports "Success; the contents match": then and *only then* is it meaningful to look at the code that attempts to load the `Image`. In this scenario, and assuming that `c:\Some\Photo.jpg` loads in most other image loading tools ("paint", etc) - then it is *possible* that `Image` doesn't recognise the subformat. But my guess is that it is going to say "Failure; the contents are different".

Note that `Convert.ToBase64String` here is used solely as a lazy way to check binary equivalence. You wouldn't use it like this in production code, but it is fine for this purpose.